# Why the cost time is difference between those two case about postgresql meterialized view?

Tags: postgresql, performance, view, common-table-expression, materialized

everyone.
In postgresql 12, i have a materialized view like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv
AS
  WITH cte AS (SELECT ...), cte2 AS (SELECT ...) SELECT ...
WITH DATA;
```

when i invoke
`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv`, or perform this command in linux crontab, it cost 4 hours.

but i perform `WITH cte AS (SELECT ...), cte2 AS (SELECT ...) SELECT ...` in pgadmin4 Query Tool, it only cost 7 seconds.

I don't know why it's too diffrence. I would like to cost 7 seconds in crontab, What shoud i do?

Comment: What if you run `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` with pgAdmin?

Comment: It cost 4 hours.

Comment: Then it is hard to believe, unless your storage has massive problems with writing.

Comment: create new materialized view with data use the same sql statements with pgadmin4, it cost about 10 seconds. but run ```REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW``` it cost 4 hours.

Comment: What is the performance if you run `CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT ...;` with your query?

Comment: There is no ```UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT``` statements, only some ```SELECT, JOIN, GROUP BY``` in cte

Comment: Sorry, I meant `CREATE TABLE test AS WITH /* your CTEs */ SELECT ...;`. Essentially, use `CREATE TABLE AS` instead of `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE test AS``` cost 7 seconds

Comment: Well, then use that rather than a materialized view. But I don't think that is possible; the queries must be different.

Comment: another question similer to this, may be the same reason. ```CREATE VIEW v1 AS /* CTEs */ SELECT ...``` WHEN use ```SELECT * FROM v1``` cost 5 seconds, use ```SELECT * FROM v1 LIMIT 10``` cost 3 hours.

Comment: Aha. If you add `LIMIT 10`, that changes everything. Is there anything like that in your present case?

Comment: no ```LIMIT``` in MATERIALIZED VIEW

Answer (score 0):

may be i find the reason, but i am not sure.

in `WITH cte AS (SELECT ...), cte2 AS (SELECT ...) SELECT ...`, there are two foreign data wrapper tables. I copy fdw table to local use `CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM fdw.table_name`, and replace fdw table use local table in cte. When i invoke
`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv AS ... WITH DATA` it cost 12 seconds,  `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_name`, it cost 2 seconds.

I think foreign data wrapper is the reason. why fdw cost so many times?

not network speed, -> `SELECT * FROM fdw.table_name` only cost seconds.

may be some transform statements in fdw, -> when `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`(use fdw table), cpu work 100% in whole 4 hours.